Conditional Maximization of a Binary Matrix
Given an $L \times N$ matrix $A$ with only binary values, $A_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$, and a vector $b$ with $b_j = 2^{j-1}$, I want to find a matrix $\tilde{A}$ that maximizes $\tilde{c}=\tilde{A}b$, subject to the following conditions.
Conditions: $\tilde{A}$ must be obtained from $A$ via a sequence of the following operations:

Permute the rows
Permute the columns
Apply logical-not to a full row, i.e., changing every 0 in the row to 1 and every 1 to a 0

Also, $\tilde{c}=\tilde{A}b$ must satisfy $\tilde{c}_L > \tilde{c}_{L-1} > \cdots > \tilde{c}_1$.
Maximization: By "maximizes $c$", I am referring to the lexicographic order on the reverse of $c$.  In other words, I want to maximize $c_L$; with ties resolved by maximizing $c_{L-1}$; and ties to that resolved by maximizing $c_{L-2}$; and so on.
Is there an efficient way to solve this optimization problem?
The parameters are of order $N < 2^L$, with $L \approx 5$ to $L \approx 10$.
While one can do this easily for a single $A$, this is a bottleneck in a larger code for me and gets called all the time, so I'm looking for a faster solution.
Example:
$
A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \implies c_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\ 2 \\ 9 \\ 12
\end{pmatrix}
$
Now I can do three things, permute rows and columns of $A$ and use the not-operation on a row. E.g. using the not-operation on row $3$ would result in
$
A'_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
Optimizing $c_4$ first an then the others, such that all of them are maximal, I would arrive at
$
\tilde{A}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \implies \tilde{c}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
9 \\ 10 \\ 12 \\ 14
\end{pmatrix}
$
While row $4$ is clear, as if can have three $1s$, row $2$ and $3$ are not, as they can be interchanged and still resulting at the same $\tilde{A_1}$ by the operations 1-3.
Now for some inputs $A$ one might come up with a $c_x = \tilde{c}_x$, but $c_y < \tilde{c}_y$ with $x > y$. So $c_y$ is conditioned on $c_x$. I want my algorithm always to result in $\tilde{c}$.
My approach so far:

One can map the $\max(c_i)$ condition on a scalar $k = \max(d A b)$ with $b$ as above and $d_i = 2^{N i}$ being a row-vector. Maximizing $k$ leads to the same solution as in the initial problem. But $d_i$ tend to get very large and I'm not sure how the suitable algorithm-type is called and don't know the complexity of this approach.
Using dynamic programming one can check the maximal number of $1s$ in a row, permute rows, columns and use logical-not to maximize $c_L$.
If two rows have the same number of $1s$, create two branches and compare them in the next iteration. This next iteration tries then to optimize $c_{L-1}$ the same way, given the constraints imposed by $c_L$ and so on. This results a maximal $\tilde{A}$, but one might have to create many different branches, making it computationally expensive. I don't have a complexity either, as it heavily depends on the input $A$.


I checked your rephrasing of my question and it is correct. Thank you for your effort!

There is a solution with something like $\tilde{O}(L!)$ complexity.
Enumerate all permutations of the $L$ rows.  Consider one such permutation, and permute the rows accordingly.  Then apply the following iterative procedure:

For the first row, if there are more 0's than 1's, negate the first row.  Then, permute the columns so that all 1's are to the left of every 0, in the first row.  Let $S_1$ denote the set of columns with 1's in the first row.

Next, for the second row, if there are more 0's than 1's in the $S_1$ columns of the second row, negate the second row.  Then, permute the columns so that, in the second row, all 1's in $S_1$ are to the left of all 0's in $S_1$.  Now let $S_2$ be the set of columns that are in $S_1$ and have a 1 in the second row.  If this makes $S_2$ empty, instead let $S_2$ be the set of columns that are to the right of everything in $S_1$ and have a 1 in the second row.

Repeat for each row.


You can use early termination, to skip all permutations with a particular prefix if they lead to a non-optimal solution.
This is roughly equivalent to your second approach (which you describe as "dynamic programming", though I don't see how dynamic programming comes into it).  It makes explicit that, no matter how much branching you might need to do, it won't be worse than exploring $L!$ branches.  Since you say $L$ is typically 5..10, this means the number of steps will typically be at most $5! .. 10!$, i.e., from about 120 to about $3.6$ million.  In practice I expect that the actual number will be far less, as normally there will be only a few ties and so we'll only need to consider a tiny fraction of all permutations.

Thank you for your answer! This is actually the approach I tried to describe in my second approach and I'm using so far. I was hoping that I miss something and that there might be some algorithmic trick that reduces computation time. And you are also right, about the part that there are only a few ties, that's why I didn't give it the complexity of $\mathcal{O}(L!)$, as there is usually a structure to the columns (two are never the same) and ties are not that common.

@Dan, Cool.  For small $L$, I would guess this will often be pretty fast and hard to beat.  Just a guess, there could always be some cleverer approach that I'm not thinking of.
